# What does "to be at the upper end" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Earlier this month, Goldman Sachs downgraded stocks to "underweight" as part of its 3-month asset allocation citing global equities to be at the upper end of their "fat and flat range."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/08/29/banks-are-preparing-for-an-economic-nuclear-winter.html

Comment: A range is a continuum that has upper and lower ends. Do you know what 'upper'  means? 'Range'? A rainbow can be thought to have  upper and lower ends, also.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: I think of rainbow as simply having two lower ends: the one next to the crock of gold, and the one that I am nearest to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At the upper end" is basically a statistical or accounting term. One definition is:

> A previously defined range, which has both a minimum and maximum, will have a "lower end" and an "upper end".

So: Goldman Sachs had defined a "fat and flat range" of (say) `-1.0%` to `2.5%`. "At the upper end" could imply anything from (around) `2.35%` to `2.5%` - probably not anything over their previous maximum though.